# Having 2 coordinates calculating the 90 degree angle formula of the next point

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I have 2 coordinates, what would be the 90 degree formula to the next point I am drawing?

[image]

Say

```
A = 50.88259382849774,6.003988087177277
B = 50.88269282423443,6.0036662220954895
x = ?
```

Is it possible to calculate if a coordinate is on the 90 degree angle point of AB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A = (a_1, a_2)$ and if $B = (b_1, b_2)$ then a point $(x_1, x_2)$ is on the line perpendicular to $AB$ through $B$ (your "x.") if and only if $(b_1-a_1)(x_1-b_1) + (b_2 - a_2)(x_2 - b_2) = 0$. This follows from the geometric definition of the dot product.

Comment: Alright I'm not very good at math so give me a little time to understand it haha (I have to read it carefuly over and over again)

Comment: Ah okay I get it so as long as the formula results in 0 the angle would be 90 degrees. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Unit maybe you can help me with this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548841/calculate-point-coordinates

Comment: Hey @Unit. I'm not super great at geometry. I'm sorry about that. Lets say I pick x1 as a point on ab line. and I wanted my x line to be a particular length lets say 'n'. Given n what would the formula be to get x2?