# Having 2 coordinates putting the third coordinate on the closest 90 degree point

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I've got a follow-up question for the previously asked and answered question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048004/having-2-coordinates-calculating-the-90-degree-angle-formula-of-the-next-point)

What I am trying to do now is that when I have a third coordinate I want it to be converted to the closest point on the x line.

[image]

This is what I got and it works with small coordinates but as soon as I use large coordinates it goes wrong.

First I use this formula (credits to Unit):

```
(b1−a1)(x1−b1)+(b2−a2)(x2−b2)
```

Example:

```
having 
A = 8,4
B = 4,8
C = 0,8

(4-8)(0-4)+(8-4)(8-8) = 16
```

So afterwards to get the closest point to the x line I do this:

```
(√16)/2 = 2
```

If it's a negative number I count the result down on the x-axis and I count the result up on the y-axis and if it's a positive number I do it the other way around so I would get (2,6) as a result which results as 0 in the formula.

This works perfectly for me but when I use real coordinates with 15 decimals it doesn't work right.

This is what I get with real coordinates

[image]

C extends too much while I used the point where the red spot is in the formula, and it should be somewhere very close to the red spot.

Comment: unsure what the problem is C is not on line x , (if only because the formla doesn't equal 0) also " If it's a negative number I count the result down on the x-axis and I count the result up on the y-axis and if it's a positive number " is not right or clear to me

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the way you go on about is not good

Given points $ A (a_1, a_2) $ and $ B (b_1, b_2) $

and you want to find a point C on the x axis $(c_2=0)$

you get:

$ (b_1 − a_1)(c_1 − b_1) + (b_2 − a_2)(c_2 −b_2) = 0 $

$ (b_1 − a_1)(C_1 − b_1) + (b_2 − a_2)(0 −b_2) =0 $

$ c_1(b_1 − a_1) − b_1(b_1 − a_1) - b_2 (b_2 − a_2) =0 $

$ c_1(b_1 − a_1) = b_1(b_1 − a_1) + b_2 (b_2 − a_2) $

$ c_1(b_1 − a_1) = b_1^2 − b_1a_1 + b_2^2 − b_2a_2 $

$$ c_1 = \frac{b_1^2+b_2^2 -b_1a_1 -b_2a_2}{b_1−a_1} $$

or

if you want to find a point D on the y axis $(d_1=0)$

$ (b_1 − a_1)(d_1 − b_1) + (b_2 − a_2)(d_2 −b_2) = 0 $

$ (b_1 − a_1)(0 − b_1) + (b_2 − a_2)(d_2 −b_2) =0 $

$ (b_1 − a_1) (− b_1) + (b_2 − a_2)(d_2)  + (b_2 − a_2)(− b_2) = 0 $

$ -b_1(b_1 − a_1) + d_2(b_2 − a_2)  -b_2 (b_2 − a_2) = 0 $

$ d_2(b_2 − a_2) =  b_1(b_1 − a_1) +b_2 (b_2 − a_2)  $

$ d_2(b_2 − a_2) = b_1^2 − b_1a_1 + b_2^2 − b_2a_2 $

$$ d_2 = \frac{b_1^2 + b_2^2 - b_1a_1 - b_2a_2}{b_2 − a_2} $$